# how to remove elements from arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

For my deleteTask method, I want to be able to delete tasks that are marked as completed but I have been given with this error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:1, Size: 1 (in java.util.ArrayList).
```

Can anyone help me?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TaskManager
{
private ArrayList<Task>tasks;
private int nextTaskId;

public TaskManager(){
    tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
    nextTaskId = 1;
}

public int getCount(){
    return tasks.size();
}

public String addTask(String description, int estimatedLength){
    Task task1 = new Task(nextTaskId, description, estimatedLength);
    tasks.add(task1);
    boolean add = true;
    if (tasks.contains(task1) == true){
        nextTaskId++;
        return "Task added.";
    }else{
        return "Error: not added.";
    }

    /*ArrayList<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
    for(int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++){
    Task taskatm = new Task();
    task.add(taskatm);
    }
    return "sq";*/

}

public Task findById(int ID){
    int i = 0;
    while(i < tasks.size()){
        Task task = tasks.get(i);
        i++;
        if(task.getId() == ID){
            return task;

        }
    }
    return null;
}

public Task setCompleted(int completedId){
    if(findById(completedId) != null){
        findById(completedId).setDone();
        return findById(completedId);

    }
    return null;
}

public Task deleteTask(int deleteId){
    if(setCompleted(deleteId) != null){
        return tasks.remove(deleteId);
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList` index starts at 0. So if you want to remove the first (and only) element, you remove the element at position 0.

Comment: when will you call  deleteTask(int deleteId) ? check 'deletedId' ? may be it is exceed then actual size

Answer (score 0):

Start `newTaskID` at 0 instead of 1...

```
public TaskManager(){
    tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
    nextTaskId = 0;
}
```

Arrays in `Java` are 0 based so the first element in the array is at index 0.

The problem with your logic however is if you remove an element then the indexes of the elements after the removed element will change. You either need to update the id's for the elements after the removed element or change the way you are deleting. You could search for the element in the list with the matching id then delete that element from the found index.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, array indexes start at 0, not 1. So to get the only element in an array with 1 element, you would say tasks.get(0) rather than tasks.get(1).

Answer (score 0):

Indexes in ArrayList are zero-based (same goes for regular arrays in Java), so either initalize your id with 0:

```
nextTaskId = 0;
```

inside the constructor or subtract 1 from id when removing task from list:

```
return tasks.remove(deleteId-1);
```

Your logic will work until you delete some task. Then your ids will be bigger that list size. I think it would be better to use

```
return tasks.remove(findById(completedId));
```

When you are not sure how some class or particular method works always reffer to [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int))